# Finding all functions: $f(x(2y+1))=f(x(y+1))+f(x)f(y)$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, complex-numbers, contest-math

Need to find all functions from integers to complex that satisfy for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$:

$f(x(2y+1))=f(x(y+1))+f(x)f(y)$

Any help would be great.

Comment: F is defined into R or Z?

Comment: OP states $f$ is complex valued

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: For the start, insert some values for $x$ or $y$ to get simpler relations. Suggest $x=1$, $y=0$, $x=0$

Comment: Do you have a reason to think this problem has a nice solution, or was this just pulled out of thin air?

Comment: I believe it has. I edit that $x, y$ are integers. I missed that one.